# Unable to extract result from geocode callback/function

Tags: javascript, callback

I am having trouble extracting data from the following function which only works with an alert(content) as the next line but obviously this has to be removed! What am I doing wrong please?

```
var address = [];
var content;
geocoder.geocode({'latLng': Marker.getPosition()}, function(responses, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
            address = (responses[0].formatted_address).split(',');
            for (i =0; i < address.length; i++) {
                content += '<div>' + address[i] + '</div>';
            }
        }
    } 
});

content += content '<br>Last line</div>';
```

The above line does not include the above geocode content at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback is async, you can use the value only inside the callback.

```
content += content '<br>Last line</div>';
```

Will execute BEFORE the callback fires.

[Please read this](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_get_and_use_the_server_response_from_an_AJAX_request.3F) regarding handling server data got by AJAX.

Comment: But what I dont understand is why the line 'alert(content);' inserted before the 'content += content '<br>Last line</div>';' forces it to work?